# Code not executing when command comes over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, processing

I'm using a **HC-05** Bluetooth Device and an **Arduino Mega** (*not the focus, but I thought I would include it*).

I want to have a LED turn on and off with the click of the button in `processing`. My `processing` code is:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

String state = "Turn On";

void setup() {
    size(600, 600);

    myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0, 150, 150);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(width/2, height/2, 200, 75, 50);

  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text(state , width/2 - textWidth(state) / 2, height/2 + 16);
}

void mousePressed() {

 if (mouseX < 400 && mouseX > 200 && mouseY < 333.5 && mouseY > 266.5) {

   if (state == "Turn On") {
     state = "Turn Off";
     myPort.write('1');
   } else {
     state = "Turn On"; 
     myPort.write('0');

   } 

  }

}
```

and my arduino code is:

```c
const int ledPin = 7;
char ledState;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    ledState = Serial.read();
  }

  if (ledState == '0') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    ledState = '3';
  }

  if (ledState == '1') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    ledState = '3';
  }

}
```

Yet, the led never turns on. I know it the Bluetooth signal goes through because the `RX` light on the Arduino flashes, meaning it came through, but the light never turns on.

What is the problem with the code? I suspect I may be reading the data wrong in the Arduino program, except this method worked a few days ago...

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***I figured it out (after 5 days - didn't ask question right away)!***

Don't make any connections if the Arduino is connected to the computer, because data is already going through the cable to the Arduino, taking place of the RX and TX pins, otherwise the RX and TX pins will negatively affect your results. But, if you are being powered externally connect the RX and TX pins (as there is no cable). The module seems to be kind of finicky and I might I have something wrong, but after this many days of debugging, I doubt it. I hope this helps! Cheers!

---

**EDIT**: It actually has to do with the code, and the problem in the code makes the above work. The problem is `Serial.list()[0]`, this finds the thing on the top of the list. Which, is actually the Arduino USB cable! So, Processing was communicating with the Arduino via the cable. So that is why it works to take the RX and TX pins out, they weren't being used. The reason I think it didn't work when the RX and TX pins were in, is that I think that the Arduino's RX and TX pins have precedence over the USB cable meaning that the Arduino was only ***kind of*** listening to the cable, hence why the RX indicator flashed.

So moving on, it worked when I unplugged it from the computer because the Arduino COM disappeared meaning the top COM was the Bluetooth itself. So it actually communicated to the Bluetooth module which sent info along its TX pin to the Arduino's RX pin, and the Arduino executed the command.

So, in final conclusion, it is better to look in device manager and find out the module's COM and use that instead of `Serial.list()[0]`, which can lead to unexpected results. So, for the final time... Cheers!

---

**FINAL EDIT**: My last statement has been confirmed by my tests, so for the final, final time... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have a flag in your arduino code that holds a 0 or a 1, and you are comparing it to "0" the character (which is equivalent to 48).

```
if (ledState == "0") {
```

Lose the quotes on the 0 there.  It's an int.  A number.  Not a String.

Also note that you set ledState to 0 in both cases.  I have a feeling that is a mistake as well.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't a mistake that was so that the code didn't execute again.